# Wifi issues but no proprietary drivers available

Tags: drivers, 22.04, iwlwifi

I am having issues with the Wifi at my University. It shows up in the network settings, but when I try to connect it just keeps loading without ever connecting. I suspect this is an issue with my drivers, as the wifi works on my phone.

Under "Software & Updates", I have checked the box for proprietary drivers. However, the "Additional drivers" tab says that "No additional drivers are available" and "No proprietary drivers are in use".

`ubuntu-drivers list` and `ubuntu-drivers list-oem` return nothing, `ubuntu-drivers install` just says that "All the available drivers are already installed". I read that `iwlwifi` is the default driver for Intel network devices, but `apt list --installed | grep iwlwifi` shows nothing.

**Does this mean literally no drivers exist for my network device? If its not the drivers, what other way would there be of fixing my wifi?**

I am on Ubuntu 22.04 with a Lenovo IdeaPad Slim 5 14IRL8. My network hardware is this:

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 01
       serial: c0:a5:e8:20:a2:7e
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.5.0-17-generic firmware=83.e8f84e98.0 so-a0-hr-b0-83.uc ip=192.168.74.141 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:6001144000-6001147fff
```

Comment: iwlwifi is included with the kernel. It is Intel, so it's free and not proprietary. Look in `lsmod` and `lspci -vnvn`

Comment: Your output clearly says: *driver=iwlwifi*. You have a driver. Are there multiple instances of the university SSID? `nmcli device wifi list`

Comment: Please [edit] with https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/1004020

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.